# Empty string ends for loop

Tags: c

What's wrong in the below program (What's happening here)? It should break the for loop after the user inserts empty string (presses only ENTER), but in my case it ends in endless for loop. I tried what is in the comments with no success.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>                                      

struct S {
  char str [10];
};

int main(void)
{
  int n;
  struct S strings [10];
  for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    # fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", strings[n].str);
    if (strlen(strings[n].str) == 0)
      break;
    # getchar();
  }
  printf("done");
  return 0;
}
```

When I replace `scanf` with `gets(strings[n].str);` *done* is never printed. How would you fix it?

[This](http://pastebin.com/QB6JC0ZU) sample solution works. Is there a difference in comparison to my code?

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but please just avoid using `scanf`; it's notoriously hard to use, and the way you're using it is susceptible to a buffer overflow. (And *never* use `gets`). http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: `scanf("%s", strings[n].str);` expects at least one non-whitespace character. `scanf` will not return until it finds one.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, note that I tried `gets` too which is used in sample solution by Chuck Allison too.

Answer (score 5):

The enter key is not empty string, it is an ascii character or rather two characters a CR and LF (on Windows).

Comment: end of line character depends, in *nix it is LF, Win: CRLF Mac CR , check : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Yes I know that - but I was just talking about Windows - not that the others don't matter :-)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use strlen to find out if the input is empty.  As others have said, when you press ENTER you get one or two characters sent to you.

You could instead check the first character in the string and see if it is `'\n'` or `'\r'`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns exactly what you've input... i.e. a crlf pair I'd imagine!

Comment: The word "returns" here is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `scanf` is that it expects something, not an empty string. You solve this by using e.g. `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```
if (fgets(strings[n].str, sizeof(strings[n].str), stdin))
{
    /* You got a string, it will contain the newline! */
}
```